# Prove: If the GCD(ab,c)=1, then GCD(a,c)=1 and GCD(b,c)=1.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I'm taking abstract algebra right now and I don't know where to begin with this question.

Comment: Hint:prove the contrapositive

Comment: Are you sure your question is posted correctly? If $(ab,c)=1\Rightarrow \exists m,n\in \mathbb Z$ such that $abm+cn=1\Rightarrow b(am)+cn=1\Rightarrow (b,c)=1$.

Comment: @Iulia Also $a(bm)+cn=1\,\Rightarrow\, (a,c)=1$, and we're done with the proof.

Comment: By contrapositive, just think: what happens if $gcd(a,c)\neq 1$... then $a$ and $c$ have a common factor.  Does $ab$ also have this common factor?

Answer (score 1):

Since given that $(ab,c)=1$ and to prove $(a,c)=1$. First let $(a,c)=d$, where $d$ is the $gcd$. We have to show $d=1$. Since $d = (a, c)$, we have $d|a$. Hence, $d|ab$. The fact that $(ab,c)=1$ can be rewritten as $abx+cy=1$, where $x$ and $y$ are some integers. Since also $d|c$ (remember that $d = (a, c)$), we have $d|(abx+cy)$ and thus $d|1$; hence $d=1$. Similarly you can do the next one.